# Swagger Not Displaying Collection Query String Whitelist

Tags: php, swagger, laminas-api-tools

In my API using Apigility I have some optional query parameters added to my Collection Query String Whitelist but they do not show up in the Swagger documentation.  Is there a special way to reference them to show up in the docs?

Comment: Please add some sample code. What are these _optional query parameters_?

Comment: @zett42  page which is the page size and type which is a filter of the get request